# Observer or event not working in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, onepage-checkout

Hello I'm trying to use the event "checkout_submit_all_after" but it doesn't work.

I'm using the OneStep Checkout by Amasty in Magento 1.9.1

Here is my config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <segundoplano_customerprescription>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription</module>
                <frontName>customerprescription</frontName>
            </args>
        </segundoplano_customerprescription>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <module>
                <file>CustomerPrescription.xml</file>
            </module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <observers>
                <segundoplano_customerprescription>
                    <class>SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>savePresciption</method>
                </segundoplano_customerprescription>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

My etc/modules/SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription>
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription>
     </modules>
 </config>
```

And My Observer.php

```
<?php

class SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription_Model_Observer{

    public function savePrescription($observer){
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->savePrescription();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with third party extension. use this `sales_order_place_after`

```
<sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <segundoplano_customerprescription>>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>SegundoPlano_CustomerPrescription_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>billingvalidation</method>
                </segundoplano_customerprescription>>
            </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

Comment: I tried differents events but it doesn´t work

Comment: any thing in `var/log` you module is listed in backend?

Comment: nothing important :(

Comment: try `Mage::log('it working ')` then check the log file .. it's print anything?

Comment: It not print anything: I put the log in the Observer before " $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();"

Comment: you have to check for output `var/log/system.log` file

Comment: Yes but it does not appear in `system.log`

Comment: check you module is listing in module list and make sure cache is disabled

Comment: Yes the module appear in the list of all modules, and it is active. The cache is disabled also.

Comment: disabled the amasty extension then try it

Comment: I tried too but it doesn't work yet